# Upsert table using PySpark in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a table in a SQL Server database

```
create table person (Name varchar(255), Surname varchar(255))
```

And I am trying a simple upsert operation with PySpark:

```
# Read data from the "person" table
person_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=database_url, table="person", properties=properties)

# Retrieve all records from the "person" table
person_df.show()

# Check if the person with name 'Jack' already exists
existing_records = person_df.filter(person_df["Name"] == "Jack")

if existing_records.count() == 0:
    # Person with name 'Jack' doesn't exist, so add them to the DataFrame
    print("Not found")
    new_person = [("Jack", "Brown")]
    new_person_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_person, ["Name", "Surname"])
    updated_person_df = person_df.union(new_person_df)
else:
    print("Found")
    # Person with name 'Jack' already exists, so update their surname to 'Brown'
    updated_person_df = person_df.withColumn("Surname", F.when(person_df["Name"] == "Jack", "White")
                                              .otherwise(person_df["Surname"]))

# Show the updated data
updated_person_df.show()

# Save the updated data back to the "person" table
updated_person_df.write.jdbc(url=database_url,
                             table="person",
                             properties=properties,
                             mode="overwrite")
```

This works well if there is no record in the table.
But after inserting the record, even if the updated_person_df dataframe is correct, this operation deletes all the records in the table.

Comment: Mode = overwrite might have something to do with overwriting

Answer (score 0):

The mode="overwrite" option in PySpark's JDBC write operation will completely drop the existing table and recreate it with the data from your DataFrame. This is why, after the initial insert, every subsequent run of this code wipes out the existing data.

To achieve true upsert behavior, you have a few options depending on the capabilities of your SQL Server database and your preferences.

You can use MERGE statement as a solution

```
merge_sql = """
  MERGE INTO person AS target
  USING updated_person_df AS source
  ON target.Name = source.Name
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET Surname = source.surname
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Name, Surname)
      VALUES (source.Name, source.Surname);
"""

spark.sql(merge_sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue with `mode = "overwrite"` that might be the reason for deleting the records in the table. Modify the code with `mode = "append"`:

```
else:
    print("Found")
    # Person with name 'Jack' already exists, so update their surname to 'Brown'
    updated_person_df = person_df.withColumn("Surname", F.when(person_df["Name"] == "Jack", "Brown")
                                              .otherwise(person_df["Surname"]))

# Save the updated data back to the "person" table
updated_person_df.write.jdbc(url=database_url,
                             table="person",
                             properties=properties,
                             mode="append")
```

It will add the same name with a different surname record to the SQL table as shown below:

| Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | Back |
| Jack | Brown |

Here is the complete code for your reference:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Upsert Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Database connection properties
database_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db;"
properties = {
    "user": "<userName>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

# Read data from the "person" table
person_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=database_url, table="person", properties=properties)

# Check if the person with name 'Jack' already exists
existing_records = person_df.filter(person_df["Name"] == "Jack")

if existing_records.count() == 0:
    # Person with name 'Jack' doesn't exist, so add them to the DataFrame
    print("Not found")
    new_person = [("Jack", "Brown")]
    new_person_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_person, ["Name", "Surname"])
    updated_person_df = person_df.union(new_person_df)
else:
    print("Found")
    # Person with name 'Jack' already exists, so update their surname to 'Brown'
    updated_person_df = person_df.withColumn("Surname", F.when(person_df["Name"] == "Jack", "Brown")
                                              .otherwise(person_df["Surname"]))

# Save the updated data back to the "person" table
updated_person_df.write.jdbc(url=database_url,
                             table="person",
                             properties=properties,
                             mode="append")  # Append mode to add new records or update existing ones
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to append. I want to update the current record.

Comment: To update recored in azure sql database table you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1225563/how-to-update-a-azure-sql-table-using-python) once.